# Facebook4j access token error 2500

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-java-api

I would like get data from facebook with facebook4j library, but I received this error

> An active access token must be used to query information about the
>   current user. code - 2500

The code:

```
ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    confBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
    confBuilder.setOAuthAppId("MY ID APP");
    confBuilder.setOAuthAppSecret("MY APP SECRET");
    confBuilder.setUseSSL(true);
    confBuilder.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
    Configuration configuration = confBuilder.build();

    FacebookFactory facebookFactory = new FacebookFactory(configuration );
    Facebook facebookClient = facebookFactory.getInstance();
    AccessToken accessToken = null;    

     OAuthSupport oAuthSupport = new OAuthAuthorization(configuration );
     accessToken = oAuthSupport.getOAuthAppAccessToken();

    facebookClient.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

    ResponseList<Post> feeds = facebookClient.getHome(new Reading().limit(1000));
```

Comment: No reply? Please help me...

Comment: As the error suggests, you need an [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

Comment: Hello @Tonj83 I'm stuck with same error, did you found solution with facebook4j ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You go to the following link: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
2. There you choose your app, which you created and want to access from.
3. .setOAuthAccessToken("The User Access Token")
4. accessToken = oAuthSupport.getOAuthAccessToken(); // NOT AppAccessToken!!!

Then it should work